# Comparing Locations Based on Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make an SQL query where it shows data based off a comparison.  This would involve using a table that tracks inventory for each day, called InventoryByDate.  What I need it to do is to show all inventory that was in location "lost" yesterday, and then in any other location today.  Have not really seen any examples of something like this so assistance would be appreciated.

((InventoryDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -1) AND LocationName = 'LOST') AND (InventoryDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND NOT LocationName = 'LOST'))

I was hoping parenthesis would allow this but I am not getting anything when executed

Comment: Always best to provide Sample Data and Desired Results.

Comment: InventoryDate cannot be yesterday and today on the same record, perhaps you meant to use 'OR' instead of 'AND'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First when asking a question like this you should be providing demo data, and preferably a demo object, or objects as required.

Let me walk through what that would look like:

```
DECLARE @ProductsAndLocations TABLE (ProductID INT, LocationID INT, ArrivedDate DATE)
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(100), SKU NVARCHAR(10), Barcode NVARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Products (Name, SKU, Barcode) VALUES
('Black Hat',     'APHAT01BLK', '123456789'),
('White Hat',     'APHAT01WHT', '123456788'),
('Red Hat',       'APHAT01RED', '123456789'),
('Black T-Shirt', 'APTSH01BLK', '123456779'),
('White T-Shirt', 'APTSH01WHT', '123456778'),
('Red T-Shirt',   'APTSH01RED', '123456777')

INSERT INTO @Locations (Name) VALUES
('Main Store'),
('Mall Stand'),
('Lost')

INSERT INTO @ProductsAndLocations (ProductID, LocationID, ArrivedDate) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-11-08'), (1, 3, '2022-11-09'), (1, 2, '2022-11-10'),
(2, 1, '2022-11-08'), (2, 3, '2022-11-09'), (2, 2, '2022-11-10'),
(3, 1, '2022-11-08'), (3, 2, '2022-11-08'),
(4, 1, '2022-11-08'), (5, 1, '2022-11-09'), (6, 1, '2022-11-10')

SELECT *
  FROM @Products p
    INNER JOIN @ProductsAndLocations pl
      ON p.ID = pl.ProductID
    INNER JOIN @Locations l
      ON pl.LocationID = l.ID
```

```
ID  Name            SKU         Barcode     ProductID   LocationID  ArrivedDate     ID  Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Black Hat       APHAT01BLK  123456789   1           1           2022-11-08      1   Main Store
1   Black Hat       APHAT01BLK  123456789   1           3           2022-11-09      3   Lost
1   Black Hat       APHAT01BLK  123456789   1           2           2022-11-10      2   Mall Stand
2   White Hat       APHAT01WHT  123456788   2           1           2022-11-08      1   Main Store
2   White Hat       APHAT01WHT  123456788   2           3           2022-11-09      3   Lost
2   White Hat       APHAT01WHT  123456788   2           2           2022-11-10      2   Mall Stand
3   Red Hat         APHAT01RED  123456789   3           1           2022-11-08      1   Main Store
3   Red Hat         APHAT01RED  123456789   3           2           2022-11-08      2   Mall Stand
4   Black T-Shirt   APTSH01BLK  123456779   4           1           2022-11-08      1   Main Store
5   White T-Shirt   APTSH01WHT  123456778   5           1           2022-11-09      1   Main Store
6   Red T-Shirt     APTSH01RED  123456777   6           1           2022-11-10      1   Main Store
```

This sets up easily reproducible objects which we can use to demo what you have against what you need.

Now on to the question. You want to find items which were lost yesterday, and have a store today.

```
SELECT p.Name AS ProductName, l.Name AS YesterdayLocationName, pl.ArrivedDate AS YesterdayArrivalDate, l2.name AS TodayLocationName, pl2.ArrivedDate AS TodayArrivalDate
  FROM @ProductsAndLocations pl
    INNER JOIN @Locations l
      ON pl.LocationID = l.ID
      AND l.Name = 'Lost'
      AND pl.ArrivedDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))
    INNER JOIN @ProductsAndLocations pl2
      ON pl.LocationID <> pl2.LocationID
      AND pl.ProductID = pl2.ProductID
      AND pl.ArrivedDate < pl2.ArrivedDate
    INNER JOIN @Locations l2
      ON pl2.LocationID = l2.ID
    INNER JOIN @Products p
      ON pl.ProductID = p.ID
```

```
ProductName YesterdayLocationName   YesterdayArrivalDate    TodayLocationName   TodayArrivalDate
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Black Hat   Lost                    2022-11-09              Mall Stand          2022-11-10
White Hat   Lost                    2022-11-09              Mall Stand          2022-11-10
```

This works great if a product has a row for each date. but depending on how your tables work you might just have the arrival date, and that's all.

Not to worry, we can fill in the gaps with a little windowed function magic!

let's replace the contents of ProductsAndLocations:

```
DELETE FROM @ProductsAndLocations
INSERT INTO @ProductsAndLocations (ProductID, LocationID, ArrivedDate) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-11-04'), (1, 3, '2022-11-07'), (1, 2, '2022-11-10'),
(2, 1, '2022-11-04'), (2, 3, '2022-11-07'), (2, 2, '2022-11-10'),
(3, 1, '2022-11-04'), (3, 2, '2022-11-08'),
(4, 1, '2022-11-04'), (5, 1, '2022-11-07'), (6, 1, '2022-11-10')
```

Now we have just the spaced out ArrivedDate values.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT pl.ProductID, pl.LocationID, pl.ArrivedDate, LEAD(pl.ArrivedDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY pl.ProductID ORDER BY pl.ArrivedDate) AS LeftDate
          FROM @ProductsAndLocations pl
       ) pld
    INNER JOIN @Locations l
      ON pld.LocationID = l.ID
      AND l.Name = 'Lost'
 WHERE pld.LeftDate = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
```

Here we figure out when the next row occurs, and create a 'LeftDate' column from it. Using the value from there, and limiting to just our Lost location we can just select the rows that left the lost location yesterday:

```
ProductID   LocationID  ArrivedDate LeftDate    ID  Name
--------------------------------------------------------
1           3           2022-11-07  2022-11-10  3   Lost
2           3           2022-11-07  2022-11-10  3   Lost
```